# When to say that system has converged, in case of distance vector routing protocol?

Tags: algorithm, graph, routes, distributed

I understand that distance vector routing protocol is a distributed version of Bellman-Ford algorithm.
It is used to find the shortest-path from every node to every other node in the network.

So, every node advertises it's routing table information (computed distances to all other nodes in the network) to its neighbors and at the same learns from the neighboring nodes.

So, my question is how long does these advertisement keeps happening between the neighbors? ie, since this is a distributed system, how does each node gets to know that the entire system has converged and I should stop advertising.

Like in case of Bellman-Ford (centralized) algorithm, we can say that convergence has happened when the number of iteration is equal to one shy of number of edges in the graph (one shy of number of links in the network), and we can stop the algorithm execution...

Comment: In the real world, nodes never stop advertising, because things change.

Comment: in my knowledge it's pretty much impossible for each node to know that the network has converged. how can a node know what's happening at another side of the network?  unless you make many assumptions about the network, delays, and then find the maximum possible number of updates, and make nodes count up until that number and hope that nothing has changed in the meantime. 
look up "counting to infinity" here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1058

Comment: @user3386109: Let us say, I have simple topology, A---B---C, and let us assume the network is stable. In such a scenario, would nodes stops advertising their routes after sometime? If so, after meeting what condition would they do that?

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki: Well, I didn't mean, whether a node can know what is happening on the other side of the network. I meant when does a node stops advertising/sending information to the other nodes in the network? Bcoz, there should be an end to this advertisement isn't? As in case of centralised version of Bellman-Ford algo, wherein it stop once the number of iteration is one shy of number of edges in the network.

Comment: I think what you're asking is equivalent to what I said. If a node wants to know when to stop updating, it has to know the global state of the network. Because even if far away in the network there is a node that is still updating its distances, there is a chance that the changes will propagate up until this node. And the bad news is that with weak assumptions, you can only prove properties of the equilibrium, but you can't easily make any conclusions about the speed of convergence. You'll notice lack of proofs regarding the speed of convergence speed in the documentation of these protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little bit of more learning on the topic and search different article brought me to this below conclusion.
Below is the excerpt from Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol#Example

> None of the routers have any new shortest-paths to broadcast.
>   Therefore, none of the routers receive any new information that might
>   change their routing tables. The algorithm comes to a stop.

So what this indicates is - In the distributed network using distance vector protocol, the nodes stop advertising the information when there is no more change to their estimated shortest-path distance. And at this stage, you can call the distributed network has got converged.

1. The node in the network starts advertising its initial table (which will contain the distance information to the directly connected nodes) once it is part of the network.
2. And it keeps advertising the distance information to its neighbors until there is change to its table.

Answer (score 0):

Periodically Routers send distance vectors  to neighbours ,, it updates only if the new information present in the distance vector by comparing with old distance vector of neighbour v which is already present at the  router... There is no stopping of algorithm...